# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Not receiving any messages (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am trying to implement FCM to my android app. So far what I've got looks like this:

Get token in this service:

```
public class BackGroundNotification extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Log.d(TAG, "refreshedToken = " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token){
    //send token to server here
}
}
```

get notifications here

```
    public class FirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "powerhawkFirebaseLog";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "DID WE FUCKING MAKE IT HERE HELLLLLOOOOOOO");

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.toString());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

The problem is, when i try doing a post to the token i get when running the app i get a 200 response saying: "InvalidRegistration"

And when i send from the firebase console to the token is says "success" but the phone never recieves any notifications.

also my manifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="this has my package but im hiding it">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_official"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_official"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".URLHandlerActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ServerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_server"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />


    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".BackGroundNotification">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

you can tell from my logs the frustration I've had trying to get the message to be received. please help.

Comment: Have you tried without killing your application while sending message from firebase console?

Comment: @Jay I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this, i don't think I'm ever "killing" my application?

Comment: It seems that, some mobiles do have issue's in receiving message payload when got killed. I have faced the same issue while working with FCM, so thought it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So apparently removing the following lines from my manifest file made it work:

```
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
```